Can I run bat to shutdown PC without admin right?
I got a script that should put the PC to shutdown everyday at 19:00 but it does not work.
@echo off
set SHUTDOWN_TIME=19:00

schtasks /create /tn "DailyShutdown" /tr "shutdown /s /f /t 0" /sc daily /st %SHUTDOWN_TIME% /RL HIGHEST /F

echo
pause

I can’t run it as an administrator because I do not have the right and the password. Also, it does not work when I double click it.
Is there something wrong in the script? Or is there any other way to do it?
I am only a user and the computer is locked if I’m not using it. I will need to log in by using my password.
I expect a script that can shutdown the PC no matter I log in or not.
Can it be done?

If you want to create a task that runs with HIGHEST (ie admin) privileges, you have to do this with an account that has those privileges. Otherwise any limited user could create tasks which run as administrator. Which obviously is a bad idea ...
